# add an entry to options window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, envdte

Is there a way using EnvDTE interface to programmatically add an entry(like Environment) in the options window of Tools menu in Visual Studio using C#? I'm stuck and I don't know how to proceed 
[image]
Many thanks